# Video capture on windows 10 version 1607

Tags: video, windows-10, webcam, directshow, video-capture

May be some of you have heard about video capture issues with Windows 10 Anniversary Update (1607). The essence of all discussions in social media is that there are problems with MJPEG. Our company has developed a camera that is an UVC device and uses the YUY2 Mediaformat. It has nothing to do with MJPEG.
But trying to access with GraphEdit fails. When I try to insert the Video Capture Filter on the Graphedit Workspace I get the error:
[image: error]
With Windows 10 Version Version 1511 this worked properly. The problem comes with Win10 version 1607.
I would by happy if someone could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows 10 Anniversary Update problems are mostly related to appearance of new component between web camera and applications: Frame Server (see [related explanation](http://alax.info/blog/1686)).

Broken support for M-JPEG was a side effect, which among other was later fixed or partially fixed by [KB3176938](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3176938) via Windows Update.

The problem you mention looks related to Frame Server. You can disable it using registry and check if bypassing it makes your camera operational. If this is the case, which in turn is a likely behavior, then something is wrong in your camera and Frame Server does not like the device. It rejects the device, makes it unable to consume the device and its video feed using DirectShow API, which in turn can happen for many reasons not specifically related to media type. Apparently it is expected that the device is a webcam or alike, it should implement typical interfaces like IAMStreamConfig etc. As your device is mentioned as UVC compatible and Windows is supposed to pick it up, then there should be something that Frame Server does not like, e.g. wrong exposed capabilities.

Comment: It seems the "Something that Frame Server does not like" is the imparity of pixels (e.g. a camera with a resoltuion of 160x121). This was not a problem with all recent versions of MS Windows. But Win10/1607 reject this resolution with an inept error code.

Answer (score 0):

There was only one possibility to fix this problem: Since the problem was just with our own designed cameras and only with video formats with odd resolution values (e.g. 160x121) we changed this formats (e.g. to 160x122). The Frameserver of Windows 10 (1607) does not exept odd values in x or y dimension any longer.